# Using the top program in bash to extract cpu time into a variable

Tags: bash, time, cpu

I have an assignment in bash scripting trying to measure cpu time used for a process passed into the script by name. I can find the process id and pass it to the top program in bash. However, I haven't figured out how to extract the cpu time from the top program. for example:

top is printing out:

```
top - 00:57:07 up  6:06,  2 users,  load average: 0.46, 0.31, 0.55
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.7 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.6 id,  0.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1928720 total,  1738072 used,   190648 free,    57184 buffers
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3337 amarkovi  20   0  372m  31m  10m R   0.7  1.7  13:28.74 chromium-browse
```

all I want from this is the TIME+ field to be assigned to variable so I can add up the time and print it out by it self.

I am a noob to bash scripting so please be patient.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use `top`? It should be much simpler (once you work out the right options) to use `ps` to give you just the fields you want, then use `grep` to select just the processes you want.

Comment: I don't have to use top. I can ps but  I really don't understand the output modifiers and how to take the time value into a variable. I am a programmer and this shell options are very confusing. is used ps -p (pidof md) it gives me print out of time. What are the modifiers to use in order to only display time and assign the value to variable.

Comment: got that ps -o time  -p pid now I need to cut it and save it :)

Comment: ^^ skip header, using `ps -otime= -p pid`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an assigment i don't want to spoil all the fun :D. I'll just point you to some commands of which can help you in your endeavour : `sed`, `awk` and `cut`. With this 3 you can solve it in many ways, enjoy!